# If angles of arbitrary triangle add to 180$^\circ$, is there an isometry into the plane?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a 2-manifold with the property that for each $x\in M$ there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ around $x$ with the property that for any three points $A, B, C\in U_x$, the interior angle measure of $\triangle ABC$ is $180^\circ$. Does this necessarily imply that there exists an isometry $\phi: U_x\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$? If so, how could one go about proving its existence?

Comment: Presumably one wants to avoid or separately handle cases like $M = \Bbb R^2$ and $A, B, C$ collinear, and one really wants $\phi$ to be an isometry /onto its image/. At any rate the statement is at least essentially true, and follows from Gauss-Bonnet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, applied to small geodesic triangles, the Gauss' curvature of $M$ is identically zero. This implies that $M$ is locally isometric to the euclidean plane.

Comment: I was able to readily prove that the total curvature, $\int_M K dA=0$... but how can I translate this into proving that $K\equiv 0$ on $M$?

Comment: You have $\int_\triangle \kappa \>{\rm d}A=0$ for arbitrary small triangles $\triangle$. If $\kappa$ is assumed continuous this implies $\kappa\equiv0$ on $M$.